# Need help understanding this simple jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {

function exportTableToCSV($table, filename) {

    var $rows = $table.find('tr:has(td)'),

        // Temporary delimiter characters unlikely to be typed by keyboard
        // This is to avoid accidentally splitting the actual contents
        tmpColDelim = String.fromCharCode(11), // vertical tab character
        tmpRowDelim = String.fromCharCode(0), // null character

        // actual delimiter characters for CSV format
        colDelim = '","',
        rowDelim = '"\r\n"',

        // Grab text from table into CSV formatted string
        csv = '"' + $rows.map(function (i, row) {
            var $row = $(row),
                $cols = $row.find('td');

            return $cols.map(function (j, col) {
                var $col = $(col),
                    text = $col.text();

                return text.replace(/"/g, '""'); // escape double quotes

            }).get().join(tmpColDelim);

        }).get().join(tmpRowDelim)
            .split(tmpRowDelim).join(rowDelim)
            .split(tmpColDelim).join(colDelim) + '"',

        // Data URI
        csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv);

    $(this)
        .attr({
        'download': filename,
            'href': csvData,
            'target': '_blank'
    });
}

// This must be a hyperlink
$(".export").on('click', function (event) {
    // CSV
    exportTableToCSV.apply(this, [$('#dvData>table'), 'export.csv']);

    // IF CSV, don't do event.preventDefault() or return false
    // We actually need this to be a typical hyperlink
});
});
```

This code turns HTML table into a CSV file. I don't understand these two lines:

```
function (i, row) {
```

and

```
function (j, col) {
```

What are 'i' and 'j'? They are not used anywhere within the functions and there is no loop so where are these variables being used. Are they used within the 'map' function?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> function (i, row) {
>
> function (j, col) {
> ```

Those lines are function declarations. The functions are anonymous. `i` and `j` are the names of the arguments passed to the functions. They might not be used, but still need to be there as the name of the first argument passed to them.

See the documentation of [`jQuery.map`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) for an explanation of how the callback is called.

Comment: still didn't understand. I removed them from the functions , but the downloaded cvs file i got was empty.

Comment: Add the line `console.log(i, row);` as the first line of the function. Then watch in the console and see what the values of those two arguments are. Remove the first argument from the function declaration, and the log statement, and see the difference.

Comment: but where is 'i' and 'j' being incremented?

Comment: It isn't.  It is an argument passed to the function.  Are you familiar with how functions are called and arguments are passed?

Comment: This may be helpful:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

Comment: i thought it like every other language, but jquery looks different, you can use a function within a function and pass arguments?

Comment: jQuery is just a library; JavaScript is the language. JavaScript, as with many languages including Python, Ruby, PHP, Smalltalk, Lisp (just not C, C++ or Java), functions can be created locally inside other functions and passed around as first-class objects. JavaScript uses this extensively.

Comment: sorry but would you be able to re-write this in a way that functions are outside of each other, i can't understand whats going on.

Comment: for example, as you said 'map' function takes in 2 arguments, but in this case, return of the other function is only 1 argument which is passed to the map function above it

Answer (score 0):

jquery map function needs a callback with two parameters, the index of the element and the element.
Thus $rows.map(function(i,row){...}); will receive the index of the row (0,1...) in the first parameter and the row itself in the second one.

If you remove the i from the function call, you are only mapping the first value, and so, row instead of receiving the value of the row, will receive the index (0,1....)

Btw. The mapping is (row, index), so is wrong mapped ([check here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) in callback definition)
If they where independent functions it will be something like this

```
void map($rows)
{
    $arr = [];
    for($i=0; $i<$rows.length; $i++)
    {
        $arr.push(mapping_function($i,$rows[i]));
    }
    return $arr;
}

void  mapping_function($i, $row)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: but where is 'i' and 'j' being incremented?

Comment: i,j and row is incremented and managed by the map function, map will call that function as many times as rows are contained in $rows variable

Comment: sorry but would you be able to re-write this in a way that functions are outside of each other, i can't understand whats going on.

Comment: for example, as you said 'map' function takes in 2 arguments, but in this case, return of the other function is only 1 argument which is passed to the map function above it